# Defining paths as a set of sequences of edges in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I have a road network graph consist of set of nodes N={1,2,3,...} and set of edges between two pair of nodes as E={(1,3), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4)....}.  I want to define set of paths as well, as a set of sequences of edges, such that Links= {*((1,3),(3,2),(2,4))*,((1,3), (3,5)), *((2,3),(3,6),(6,5),(5,2))*,...}.

Here is the initialization of my code, as an example:

```
int N={1,2,3,4,5,6}
tuple edge
{int i; 
 int j;
 }
{edge} E={<1,3>, <1,5>, <2,3>, <2,4>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <3,6>, <5,6>, <5,4>, <6,4>};
```

Here I dont know how to continue to define the set of paths as a set of sequences of edges. I will be really appreciated if you can help me! thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try array of sets:

```
{int} N={1,2,3,4,5,6};
tuple edge
{int i; 
 int j;
 }
{edge} E={<1,3>, <1,5>, <2,3>, <2,4>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <3,6>, <5,6>, <5,4>, <6,4>};

{edge} Links[E]= [{<1,3>,<3,2>,<2,4>},{<1,3>, <3,5>}];

execute
{
  writeln(Links);
}
```

and then if you need a dvar boolean array

```
{int} N={1,2,3,4,5,6};
tuple edge
{int i; 
 int j;
 }
{edge} E={<1,3>, <1,5>, <2,3>, <2,4>, <3,2>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <3,6>, <5,6>, <5,4>, <6,4>};

{edge} Links[E]= [{<1,3>,<3,2>,<2,4>},{<1,3>, <3,5>}];

execute
{
  writeln(Links);
}

tuple t
{
  edge e;
  int rank;
}

{t} s=union(e in E) {<e,i> | i in 1..card(Links[e])};

execute
{
  writeln(s);
}

dvar boolean x[s];

subject to
{
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you help me as well how to use the array of sets in variables or constraint? I mean, i.e. a boolean variable xi that refers to a vehicle use the path/link or not.

dvar boolean x[Links[E]]; gives error as I expected...

Comment: Thanks but I think there is something wrong with this code. Since Links[E] is a 2D array (contains two links), I want that x[s] to be 2D. I mean; x[1] needs to refer to Link 1 which is {<1,3>,<3,2>,<2,4>} and x[2] needs to refer to Link 2 which is {<1,3>, <3,5>}.

For a trial I've just added :
`dexpr float obj= sum(e in E, i in 1..card(Links[e])) x[<e,i>];
minimize obj;
`
and expected to have x=[0 0], as the solution, but it returns with x=[0 0 0 0 0], which is equal to the edge number in Links[E] array.